# Is there anyone making actual physical badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, merchandise

Does anybody know of a company or person making physical badges? Like an embroidered patch or something? Sure, it's kind of old school, but some people like to attach pieces of flair to backpacks or whatever.

Comment: Badges!?  *BADGES?!* **WE DON'T NEED NO STEENKIN' BADGES!!!**

Comment: @Pollyanna: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges ... personally i've always preferred the *UHF* rendition: "Badgers?  Badgers?! [...]"

Answer (score 12):

Making badges is easy. The hard part is implementing badge rights management (BRM) that prevents malicious users from duplicating badges that they haven't earned.

Badge piracy is a serious issue. For every legitimate, physical badge made by hard-working badge manufacturers and developers, there are sixteen (16) illegally created badges in the world.

Fraudulent badges can be identified from their frayed edges, cheap colours that wash out in the rain and increased likelihood of being infused with narcotics and/or bloody pieces of glass. While these badges may be cheaper and easier to find than authentic badges, their quality is nowhere near the same level of standards as the real deal.

So please, if you find a badge that doesn't have the BRM seal on it, please report it to the Badge Manufacturers Association of America (BMAA).

Comment: I didn't think about that. Maybe we need badges that connect to the internet and authenticate themselves every 5 minutes.

Comment: I love your answers and comments... I just do

Comment: I hate those posers who wear frayed badges that you *just know* are brand new, like they've been a fan of the site for years.  If it's not Beta or Yearling, it shouldn't be frayed, hipster!

Comment: There must be a [defective-by-design] joke somewhere in here

Comment: This sounds exactly like what a member of BMAA's propaganda machine would say. What Mr. Posse - if that is his real name - 
fails to mention is that there is a plentitude of alternative Badge Making associations - the Association of Caribbean Badge Makers, 
the west indies badge manufacturers conglomerate, and the North American Badge Manufacturers' organization (NABMO), to list just a few - united in the struggle against the corporate monster that is the BMAA.

Comment: For years, BMAA has been dominating the badge market using unscrupulous business practices, extortion, extremely high membership fees, and lobbyism in both Washington and Brussels. The BRM seal is only the latest ploy in the BMAA's efforts to achieve total market domination. Their lobbyists are currently trying to pressure democratic lawmakers into introducing legislation making the BRM seal mandatory for *any badge sold in the U.S.*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that keeping my SO reputation up to date on a physical badge attached to my backpack is NP-hard.

Comment: badges != flair

Comment: @fretje -- since he referenced flair in the question.  I assumed he meant "blog badges".

Comment: Actually, a little LCD with wifi-enabled embedded Linux would probably work on campus, hmmm.... Download the config via USB key.  Maybe it's not so hard after all.   :-)

Comment: I meant flair in the more general sense, as in a small ornament attached to an object to show one's preference or support for something. Physical badges be flair in this case. I was referring to the "Guru" badge or the "Supporter" badge, not to the blog "flair" that you can put on your website.

Comment: @Bearddo -- ah, I see now. Make sure you put your "Supporter" badge far away from your "Athletic" badge.

Comment: With as much time as I spend in front of a computer I won't be getting any sort of "Athletic" badge anytime soon.